# Troubleshooting Keyboard Backlight Not Working On Bootcamp Windows

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, bootcamp

My keyboard backlight stopped working on my MacBook Pro TB 2017 15" in Bootcamp Windows, but it works perfectly fine on macOS. I've tried reinstalling the Apple Boot Camp drivers but that didn't fix it.

The Touch Bar works fine, especially with display brightness controls, however even though the backlight brightness up-down icons appear, tapping them does nothing. In the Boot Camp Control Panel in the Keyboard section, I've disabled the "Use all F1, F2,..." option, I've also disabled the "Adjust keyboard brightness in low light" and have set the "Turn off keyboard backlight..." to Never.

I think the ambient light sensor works fine too, as when I turn on the Windows auto display brightness it is responsive to ambient light. I'm on Windows 10 Pro 22H2 19045.2728 with Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4190.0.

I don't know where to start when it comes to debugging this issue. I don't really want to do a fresh install (even though I'm 90% sure it'll fix this issue), as I have a bunch of software I use almost daily.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked "[Apple Software Update](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208038)"?

Comment: Yup, already done so when reinstalling drivers, it says "Your software is up-to-date".